# DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized when use OmniThreadLibrary (but ok otherwise)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I need to make a long running task in the background. I'm using [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) hopping this could help me.

I use dbexpress+mssql driver. I can connect ok when is in the main thread, but get:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message
>   'DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly initialized.  Client library
>   may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the
>   driver may be missing from the system path.'.

The connections are created in each thread, not shared datamodule:

```
type
  TdbManager = class(TObject)
  private
    { private declarations }
    FCon: TSQLConnection;
  public
    { public declarations }
    procedure Open(Driver:String; aparams:TStringList);overload;
    procedure Close;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;override;
  end;

  constructor TdbManager.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FCon := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
end;

procedure TdbManager.Open(Driver: String; aparams: TStringList);
var
  i: Integer;
  key:string;
begin
  FCon.DriverName := Driver;

  for i := 0 to params.Count - 1 do
  begin
    key := params.Names[i];
    FCon.Params.Values[key] := params.Values[key];
  end;

  LogMsg('Open DB '+ Driver + ': ' + FHost + '\' + FDatabase);

  FCon.Open;
  LogMsg('Done.');
end;
```

And the background task is executed:

```
procedure TBackupPlan.OnScheduleTrigger(Sender: TScheduledEvent);
begin
  Parallel.Async(procedure
  begin
    ExecuteDataTask( Sender.Name );
  end);
end;

procedure TBackupPlan.ExecuteDataTask(const Name: String);
var
  db:TdbManager;
begin
  db := nil;

  db := TSqlServerManager.Create;
  db.Open(self.Driver, options);

  result := db;
end;
```

If I execute this directly, open ok. If I use `Parallel.Async` then get the error. What is happend here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found information about this here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbExpress_Database_Specific_Information

> **MSSQL Driver Requires Calls to CoInitialize and CoUninitialize for Console Applications and Worker Threads**
>
> The MSSQL driver does not call CoInitialize or CoUninitialize. Earlier
>   versions of the MSSQL driver, which is a COM driver, called
>   CoInitialize and CoUninitialize directly, which is not a good
>   practice. VCL applications take care of these calls for you, so VCL
>   applications do not require calling CoInitialize and CoUninitialize.
>   However, applications using the MSSQL driver in console applications
>   or in worker threads need to call CoInitialize/CoUninitialize. If this
>   call is not made, you will see the following error message: "DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be
>   missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver
>   may be missing from the system path." For help on CoInitialize, see
>   the CoInitialize Function on MSDN.